# Django models campo con solo fecha y campo con solo hora

Tags: python, django, django-models

¡Hola a todos!

Estoy haciendo una web con Django en la que se puede solicitar cita seleccionando un día y una hora... El caso es que al hacer los modelos, veo que se puede usar models.DateField() para la fecha, pero para la hora, si uso DateTimeField() sale hora pero también fecha. He estado leyendo la documentación oficial de [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/) y [fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#model-field-types) y buscado por más sitios, pero no encuentro nada que me aclare... Es más, no sé si es posible... Agradecería mucho una mano ^^

Estos son los models:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Customer(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=9)
    points = models.IntegerField()


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    price_in_points = models.IntegerField()


class Appointment(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    day = models.DateField()
    hour = # solo la hora
    complete = models.BooleanField()


class Historic(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    day = models.DateField()
    hour = # solo la hora
    complete = models.BooleanField()
```

Un saludo y espero que estéis todos bien.

Comment: Existe un campo [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#timefield), que es para guardar las horas, minutos, etc, sin guardar la fecha. Que segun entiendo, es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Hola Julio Cesar, correcto, era lo que necesitaba y lo vi justo esta mañana volviendo a leer un rato... No sé cómo se me pasó, imagino que por llevar tantas horas delante de la pantalla afecta jeje... Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte :)